# TensorFlow 2.0 GradientTape with EarlyStopping

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using Python 3.7.5 and TensorFlow 2.0's 'GradientTape' API for classification of MNIST dataset using 300 100 dense fully connected architecture. I would like to use TensorFlow's 'EarlyStopping' with GradientTape() so that the training stops according to the variable being watched or monitored and according to patience parameters.

The code I have is below:

```
# Use tf.data to batch and shuffle the dataset
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).shuffle(100).batch(batch_size)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(batch_size)

#  Choose an optimizer and loss function for training-
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001)

def create_nn_gradienttape():
    """
    Function to create neural network for use
    with GradientTape API following MNIST
    300 100 architecture
    """
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(
        Dense(
            units = 300, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal,
            input_shape = (784,)
        )
    )

    model.add(
        Dense(
            units = 100, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal
        )
    )

    model.add(
        Dense(
            units = 10, activation = 'softmax'
        )
    )

    return model

# Instantiate the model to be trained using GradientTape-
model = create_nn_gradienttape()

# Select metrics to measure the error & accuracy of model.
# These metrics accumulate the values over epochs and then
# print the overall result-
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name = 'train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name = 'test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'train_accuracy')

# Use tf.GradientTape to train the model-

@tf.function
def train_step(data, labels):
    """
    Function to perform one step of Gradient
    Descent optimization
    """

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # 'training=True' is only needed if there are layers with different
        # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
        # predictions = model(data, training=True)
        predictions = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions)

    # 'gradients' is a list variable!
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    # IMPORTANT:
    # Multiply mask with computed gradients-

    # List to hold element-wise multiplication between-
    # computed gradient and masks-
    grad_mask_mul = []

    # Perform element-wise multiplication between computed gradients and masks-
    for grad_layer, mask in zip(gradients, mask_model_stripped.trainable_weights):
        grad_mask_mul.append(tf.math.multiply(grad_layer, mask))

    # optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_mask_mul, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, predictions)

@tf.function
def test_step(data, labels):
    """
    Function to test model performance
    on testing dataset
    """
    # training=False is only needed if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    predictions = model(data)
    t_loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions)

    test_loss(t_loss)
    test_accuracy(labels, predictions)


EPOCHS = 15

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    test_accuracy.reset_states()

    for x, y in train_ds:
        train_step(x, y)

    for x_t, y_t in test_ds:
        test_step(x_t, y_t)

    template = 'Epoch {0}, Loss: {1:.4f}, Accuracy: {2:.4f}, Test Loss: {3:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {4:4f}'

    print(template.format(epoch + 1, 
                          train_loss.result(), train_accuracy.result()*100,
                          test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()*100))


    # Count number of non-zero parameters in each layer and in total-
    # print("layer-wise manner model, number of nonzero parameters in each layer are: \n")

    model_sum_params = 0

    for layer in model.trainable_weights:
        # print(tf.math.count_nonzero(layer, axis = None).numpy())
        model_sum_params += tf.math.count_nonzero(layer, axis = None).numpy()

    print("Total number of trainable parameters = {0}\n".format(model_sum_params))
```

In the code above, How can I use 'tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping' with GradientTape() API ?

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the reason or not using the callback with `fit()` but with `GradientTape`?

Comment: @thushv89 I have to use some layer-wise masking operation based on magnitude based sparse pruning for which I have to use *GradientTape* instead of *fit()* method. Is there a way to use *EarlyStopping* with *GradientTape()* ?

Comment: @Arun have you solved it yet?

Comment: @M.Innat Yes I did

Comment: Can you please post your solution?

Comment: https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/Lottery_Ticket_Hypothesis-TensorFlow_2/blob/master/Conv_6_Magnitude_based_Pruning_LTH_CIFAR10.ipynb